# Customizing Wallpaper for Apple Watch Infograph Watch Face?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

I wanted to create a watch face that has

1. a customizable wallpaper, and
2. 8 complications like the Infograph watch face.

According to [this page](https://support.apple.com/guide/watch/faces-and-features-apde9218b440/watchos), the only customizable feature of Infograph watch face is color, so if I chose this watch face I wouldn't be able to use my own wallpaper.

Clearly, my goal cannot be reached without using any third-party softwares. I tried to search on GitHub but so far I haven't found a perfect solution yet. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[image: Wallpaper but with few complications]
[image: Infograph but no wallpaper]

Answer (score 1):

Wallpaper can't be changed for the Infograph Watch face.

Even watchOS 7, currently in beta testing, doesn't allow this.

I suggest you provide feedback directly to Apple and indicate you want this ability: https://www.apple.com/feedback/watch.html